# Php Jquery Post from a button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having problems with this code it doesn't want to get the $_POST here is the code.

first i have a isset to check for the post

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteRecord'])){
    echo $_POST['deleteRecord'];
};
```

Then i have the HTML button

```
<button type="button" id="deleteRecordButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Delete Record</button>
```

And this is the jquery call to post

```
$('#deleteRecordButton').click(function(){
            $(':checkbox').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')&& $(this).attr('id') != "check_all"){
                    $.post('home.php',{deleteRecord: 1});
                    $(this).prop('checked',false);
                }
            });
        });
```

all this is in 1 php file called home.php. For some reason i can't get the $_POST any idea?

Comment: `it doesn't want to get the $_POST here is the code‍` = ?!

Comment: Your `$.post` call has no callback, where would you see the returned data?

Comment: Your PHP refers to "deleteRecord" but the ```id``` of your button is "deleteRecordButton".

Answer (score 0):

Your $.post is not getting anything back, as @adeneo said

Do something like this to see what you get back from the server:

```
$("#your_button_id").click(function () {
    var data = DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND
    $.post("home.php", data)
          .done(function (data_from_server) {
              alert(data_from_server)
              //Then you will see what your AJAX Call gets from the server
          })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR)
        });
});
```